# Cross database connection and relationships in mongoDB and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

how can I refer on database's table to another database's table in mongoDB like I have 2 database

1. Root database contain `user` table
2. company database contain `companies` table

now I want to refer `companies` table to `user` table. is there any possible way to connect this in nodejs and mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this to populate across databases in mongoose:

```js
import mongoose, { Schema, Types } from "mongoose"

const db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/company');
const db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/root');

const companySchema = new Schema({ name: String });
const Company = db1.model('Company', companySchema);

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    company: {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
        ref: Company
    }
})

const User = db2.model('User', userSchema);

const users = await User.find().populate("company")
console.log(users)
db1.close()
db2.close()
```

result:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("642d5cf980d1e56765814094"),
    name: 'myUser',
    company: {
      _id: new ObjectId("642d5cb580d1e56765814093"),
      name: 'myCompany'
    }
  }
]
```

From mongosh:

```
company> db.companies.find()
[ { _id: ObjectId("642d5cb580d1e56765814093"), name: 'myCompany' } ]
company> use root
switched to db root
root> db.users.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("642d5cf980d1e56765814094"),
    name: 'myUser',
    company: ObjectId("642d5cb580d1e56765814093")
  }
]
```

Comment: please watch the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXMuV-Zfrss, you may get the idea and refer the first comment, I got the lead but it's not enough for me

Comment: So what that video does is just connecting to 2 different databases in an Express app. One of them could just as well be a postgres, mysql or influxdb data source. Is that what you're after?

Comment: and please refer the comment of that video also, https://prnt.sc/vB92nJwdzqzi

Comment: @Smitlathiya it seem like you are providing solutions rather than, what seem like you have tried something, the code you have tried and what's failing on your part

Comment: @Smitlathiya There is not enough context in that image. Of course you can fetch data from two different databases in your app. I can try to help you if you provide some code.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/Y9gQUe0Ot4jO in this screenshot i've refer the company database's companies table to root database's user table, when i 'll request for the user's list i need all the users with their company details using populate() function in mongoose, 
user schema: https://prnt.sc/2GJAukbpVmck
user db connection: https://prnt.sc/zneTE2JjXWfw
company db connection: https://prnt.sc/1q6iLmBZVAUy
user query: https://prnt.sc/f3UUjAth35WO
if i use this query i'm getting the following error https://prnt.sc/3kQZqJUUM_JP

Comment: @Smitlathiya It was easier when I had your code in front of me. I've updated the answer with something I believe will help you.

Comment: thank you for the solution, it's working perfectly. https://prnt.sc/f1v0eMf6ggq-

Comment: @Smitlathiya I'm glad to hear! I learnt something new as well. I've never used populate across databases before.